# Bash - Print value of variable in array

Tags: arrays, bash, loops

I want to do something like this

```
A='123'
B='143'
C='999'

declare -a arr=(A B C)

for i in "{$arr[@]}"
do
     echo "@i" "$i" 
done
```

Which should give me the output of

```
A 123
B 143
C 999
```

But instead I receive the variable names, not the value in the output (I just see "A @i" in the output...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to store the variable names in the loop, rather than copy their values, then you can use the following:

```
for i in "${arr[@]}"; do
    echo "${!i}"
done
```

This means that the value of `i` is taken as a name of a variable, so you end up echoing `$A`, `$B` and `$C` in the loop.

Of course, this means that you can print the variable name at the same time, e.g. by using:

```
echo "$i: ${!i}"
```

---

It's not exactly the same, but you may also be interested in using an associative array:

```
declare -A assoc_arr=( [A]='123' [B]='143' [C]='999' )

for key in "${!assoc_arr[@]}"; do
    echo "$key: ${assoc_arr[$key]}"
done
```

Comment: Excellent, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Michael you might also be interested in using an associative array - see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to add `$`:

```
declare -a arr=("$A" "$B" "$C")
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that is an alternative for the example but in reality I would like to able to output both the variable name and the value. Is that possible?